# error mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, html

Hi can u guys help me with this error ?

> "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   object given in "blablabla" on line 31."

I've tried a lot of solutions that I've found but it still leads me to this error.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Autores
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php        
$link = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
if($link === false){
    die("ERRRO: Não foi possivel a conexão com a base de dados. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}        
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM autores';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());        
echo "<p><b>Ver todos</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>Ver por página</a></p>";       
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";        
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Autor</th><th></th> <th></th></tr>";        
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result )) {  
    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";   
    echo '<td>' . $row['a_id'] . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $row['a_nome'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
// close table>
echo "</table>";
        ?>
        <p>
            <a href="new.php">Add a new record</a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Gonçalo Pinho

Comment: **NEVER Share Database ID and Password!**

Comment: serious ... posting connection data?

Comment: You mix `mysqli_...()` and `mysql_...()` functions. That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result )) {  //you have to change mysql to mysqli
    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";   
    echo '<td>' . $row['a_id'] . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $row['a_nome'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem I didn't noticed that I missed an "i" there ^^

Comment: Welcome take care of silly mistake

Comment: @RushilPachchigar `mysqll_` that's a typo, you need to fix it. It needs to read as `mysqli_` and not 2x `l`'s.

Comment: @RushilPachchigar you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Why can't you do like this**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("HOST", "UNAME", "PASS", "Database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM autores";
$result = $link->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
// Your stuff
}
```